# SQL Server divided always take the highest value

Tags: sql, sql-server, math, division

I'm using SQL Server and I have to calculate the time needed for an appointment but I don't know how to proceed to get the highest value from the division.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I have this query:

```
select 16/5
```

and it returns

```
3
```

but I need it to return

```
4
```

How can I get this? I tried round and floor function but that's not working for me.

Comment: you need [CEILING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx) function .. `ceiling(16/5.0)`

Comment: @vkp  Thanks mate! :)

Comment: you should also note that 16/5 performs an integer division. you should get the result as a float and apply this function.. like `ceiling(1.0*16/5)`

Comment: Alternatively, for integer `x`, compute `(x+4)/5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CEILING function. Saw that this was posted in the comments already so full credit to **[vkp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3431869/vkp)**.

> CEILING(16/5.0)